# Integrals inequality

Tags: integration, inequality, definite-integrals

I have
$$A=\int_1^5{\frac{e^x}{e^x+x^2}dx}$$
$$B=\int_1^5{\frac{x^2}{e^x+x^2}dx}$$
I have already found that $A+B=4$ but now I want to prove that $AB\le4$. I don't know how. I am thinking of using the properties of integrals but nothing seems to work out for me. Any ideas?

Comment: $$\int_1^5{\frac{e^x}{e^x+x^2}dx}+\int_1^5{\frac{x^2}{e^x+x^2}dx}=2$$

$$\int_1^5{\frac{e^x}{e^x+x^2}+\frac{x^2}{e^x+x^2}dx}=2$$

$$\int_1^5{\frac{e^x+x^2}{e^x+x^2}}=2$$

$$\int_1^5{dx}=2$$

$$[x]^5_1=4$$

$$4 \ne 2$$

How?

Comment: sorry misstyped!

Comment: It is still $A+B=2$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This follows from the AM–GM inequality. Both integrals are positive, so
$$A+B=4\implies\frac{A+B}2=2\implies
\sqrt{AB}\le2\implies AB\le4$$

Answer (score 11):

While Parcly's answer is quick, it can be done without AM-GM as well if you do not happen to know/remember AM-GM.
After all, if given $A+B=4$, then the expression $AB$ can be written as $A(4-A)$ which is $-A^2+4A$. The outputs are values according to a parabola that opens down, having vertex $(2,4)$, hence $AB\le4$. Just a thought...

Comment: Which is one way to prove the AM-GM inequality for AM = 4 :)

Answer (score 1):

$((\sqrt{A})^2 -(\sqrt{B})^2)^2 \ge 0$
$(\sqrt{A})^2-2\sqrt{AB}+(\sqrt{B})^2 \ge 0$
$(\sqrt{A})^2+(\sqrt{B})^2 \ge 2\sqrt{AB}$
$A + B \ge 2\sqrt{AB}$
so $A + B = 4 \Rightarrow 4 \ge 2\sqrt{AB}$
That is $\sqrt{AB} \le 2$
Therefore $AB \le 4$